# Creating new column based on conditions from a separate dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Dataframe A:

```
     osiId                  hostName    infrastructureOnly  hostMemoryGigabytes     timeFrameEnd
0    3706509458083282923    None        False               15.998997               2022-10-08 16:00:00  
1   -3839344128100363916    None        False               15.512978               2022-10-08 16:00:00
2   -6999440164179221150    None        False               15.999073               2022-10-08 16:00:00
3   -8641005918235945332    None        True                125.644001              2022-10-08 16:00:00
4    1747872771634044177    None        False               31.262001               2022-10-08 16:00:00
```

Dataframe B:

```
df_hostunits = {'maxRam (gb)': [1.6,4,8,16,32,48,64,80,96,112,'n*16'],
        'hostUnits (full)': [0.1, 0.25, 0.50, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,'n'],
              'hostUnits (infra)': [0.03,0.075,0.15,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]}
df_hostunits = pd.DataFrame(df_hostunits)

    maxRam (gb) hostUnits (full)    hostUnits (infra)
0   1.6         0.1                 0.030
1   4           0.25                0.075
2   8           0.5                 0.150
3   16          1                   1.000
4   32          2                   1.000
5   48          3                   1.000
6   64          4                   1.000
7   80          5                   1.000
8   96          6                   1.000
9   112         7                   1.000
10  n*16        n                   1.000
```

I need new a column in dfA called hostUnits. This column would have number of host units based on dfB. A little hard to explain so example:

Row 0 in dfA has about 16gb RAM and `infrastructureOnly == False` meaning we use the `hostUnits (full)` column to calculate the number of hostUnits, so 1 host unit.

Row3 of dfA has `infrastructureOnly == True` meaning we use the `hostUnits (infra)` column of dfB to calculate hostUnits which in this case would also be 1 host unit.

If RAM falls in between two values like say 40 gb, then we always round up and depending on the infrastructure value would either be 3 or 1.

If we had an `infrastructureOnly == True` row with 438 RAM we'd used that final row in dfB to calculate host units. So 438/16 = 27.375 host units, rounded up would be 28 host units.

I hope I explained that clearly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you drop the last row from your second df, and just know that the results will be divided by 16 for any records that match that last row, you can use merge_asof to merge to the nearest higher value.

Then you can use a few lines to use one hostUnits vs the other based on infrastuctureOnly, and lastly you can divide memory by 16 for any empty rows which have infrastructureOnly as `False`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

df = pd.DataFrame({'osiId': [3706509458083282923,
  -3839344128100363916,
  -6999440164179221150,
  -8641005918235945332,
  1747872771634044177],
 'hostName': ['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None'],
 'infrastructureOnly': [False, False, False, True, False],
 'hostMemoryGigabytes': [15.998997,
  15.512978,
  15.999073,
  125.644001,
  31.262001],
 'timeFrameEnd': ['2022-10-08 16:00:00  ',
  '2022-10-08 16:00:00',
  '2022-10-08 16:00:00',
  '2022-10-08 16:00:00',
  '2022-10-08 16:00:00']})

df_hostunits = {'maxRam (gb)': [1.6,4,8,16,32,48,64,80,96,112],
        'hostUnits (full)': [0.1, 0.25, 0.50, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,],
              'hostUnits (infra)': [0.03,0.075,0.15,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]}
df_hostunits = pd.DataFrame(df_hostunits)
df.sort_values(by='hostMemoryGigabytes', inplace=True)
df = pd.merge_asof(df, df_hostunits, left_on='hostMemoryGigabytes', right_on='maxRam (gb)', direction='forward')

df['hostUnits'] = np.where(df['infrastructureOnly']==True, df['hostUnits (infra)'], df['hostUnits (full)'])
df['hostUnits'] = np.where((df['hostUnits'].isnull()) & (df['infrastructureOnly']==False), (df['hostMemoryGigabytes'] / 16).apply(math.ceil), df['hostUnits'])
df = df.fillna(1).drop(columns=['maxRam (gb)','hostUnits (full)','hostUnits (infra)'])
```

Comment: Does  `df1['hostUnits'] = np.where((df1['hostUnits'].isnull()) & (df1['infrastructureOnly']==False), round((df1['hostMemoryGigabytes'] / 16),0), df1['hostUnits'])` round to the nearest whole number? Because I need it to round up even if the value is barely over the whole number. Otherwise this works great.

Comment: updated to use math.ceil instead of round, this will give you the next closes int